# Can I apply a where condition on xpath?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have some xml which looks like

```
<LongDescription Name="Detailed Specifications">
   <Group GroupName="Model">
      <Property Key="Brand" Value="xx" />
      <Property Key="Model" Value="ss" />
   </Group>
   <Group GroupName="Spec">
      <Property Key="Name" Value="aa" />
   </Group>
   <Group GroupName="Features">
      <Property Key="Features" Value="qq" />
   </Group>
</LongDescription>
```

I want to get the value of property `Value` where `Key='Name'`. In the xml above, the answer is `aa`. Can I do this via a simple xpath expression?

I do some researches on xpath and I know how to get the value of a attribute. But I don't know how to apply a where condition on xpath. After a google on web, I only found the way how to get `text value of a tag` by a where condition, but this is not what I want.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can select the attribute:

```xml
//Property[@Key='Name']/@Value
```

In order to restrict the XPath result to a certain group of nodes, you use the `[@attributeName='attributeValue']`notation.

This example expression returns all `Property` nodes where the `Key` attribute equals name and selects the `Value` attribute from this result.

In order to get just the actual value, you can use this:

```xml
string(//Property[@Key='Name']/@Value)
```

This returns just `aa` (with your example xml).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look maybe this can help you.

```
 XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
  XPathExpression expr = null;

expr = xpath.compile("//" + fatherNode+ "[" + nodeToCompare+ "='" + value+ "']/" + node);

String resultat = (String) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

where doc is an objecte type Document.